# Can't override Mage_Review_Block_Product_View class

Tags: module, magento-1, extensions, overrides, review

I'm trying to extend Mage_Review_Block_Product_View but my new class is not called... I think it could be a typo, but I can't find it.

It is not a issue related to the code inside my class, but to the calling of class rewrite. If I make an override placing the modified class in app/code/local/Mage/Review/Block/Product/View.php it does it job.

If I try to integrate the rewrite in a module it is not called. Here me code:

module config.xml:

```
[...]
<global>
  <blocks>
    [...]
    <review>
      <rewrite>
        <form>Bbox_ExtendReview_Block_Review_Form</form>
        <product_view>Bbox_ExtendReview_Block_Review_Product_View</product_view>
      </rewrite>
    </review>
    [...]
  </blocks>
  [...]
</global>
```

Than in app/code/local/Bbox/ExtendReview/Block/Review I have:

- Form.php that is correctly called
- Product/View.php that is not called

The View.php contain the class extension:

```
<?php

class Bbox_ExtendReview_Block_Review_Product_View extends Mage_Review_Block_Product_View
{

public function getReviewsCollection()
{
    //some code...
}
```

Everything looks fine to me.. and the rewrite in Form.php is correctly working, so I don't understand way the Product/View.php is not...

I'll really appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 3):

After days of debug I've found out the solution just after I post the question here...

As Alan Storm stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690311/how-do-you-overide-a-class-that-is-called-by-another-class-with-parentmethod) it is an issue related to the order of the inheritance chain:
*Mage_Review_Block_Product_View* is extend by *Mage_Review_Block_Product_View_List* and this one doesn't know anything about my new *Bbox_ExtendReview_Block_Product_View* that correctly extends *Mage_Review_Block_Product_View* but it is never used.

I just change my code to extend *Mage_Review_Block_Product_View_List* and now everything work fine:

confing.xml:

```
<review>
    <rewrite>
      [...]           
        <product_view_list>CJM_ColorSelectorPlus_Block_Review_Product_View_List</product_view_list>
    </rewrite>
  </review>
```

than I move the code to app/code/local/Bbox/ExtendReview/Block/Review/Product/View/List.php:

```
class CJM_ColorSelectorPlus_Block_Review_Product_View_List extends Mage_Review_Block_Product_View_List
{
  //my code
}
```

I hope this could be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 2):

The class is not instantiated itself, instead `Mage_Review_Block_Product_View_List` which extends `Mage_Review_Block_Product_View`.

Rewrites do not affect child classes, so you need to add this:

```
    <product_view_list>Bbox_ExtendReview_Block_Review_Product_View_List</product_view_list>
```

and a class `Bbox_ExtendReview_Block_Review_Product_View_List` just like `Mage_Review_Block_Product_View_List` but extending your rewritten class.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The white space is not present in my config.xml I edited my question to remove that.

Comment: I updated the answer and just then found out that you already found the answer on your own.

Answer (score 1):

I have also the same issue I want to rewrite `getReviewsCollection` function from `Mage_Review_Block_Product_View` class So the process i follow is below.

Firt create My module file class like `Test_Coreoverride_Block_Review_Product_View_List` and write my function to this file class.

```
<?php
class Test_Coreoverride_Block_Review_Product_View_List extends Mage_Review_Block_Product_View
{
    public function getReviewsCollection()
    {
        if (null === $this->_reviewsCollection) {
            $this->_reviewsCollection = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()
                ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
                ->addEntityFilter('product', $this->getProduct()->getId())
                ->setDateOrder();
        }
        return $this->_reviewsCollection;
    }
}
```

and the `config.xml`

```
<blocks>
        <coreoverride>
            <class>Test_Coreoverride_Block</class>
        </coreoverride>

        <review>
            <rewrite>
                <product_view_list>Test_Coreoverride_Block_Review_Product_View_List</product_view_list>
            </rewrite>
        </review>
    </blocks>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in config.xml.

```
[...]
<global>
    <blocks>
        <review>
            <rewrite>
                <product_view>Bbox_ExtendReview_Block_Product_View</product_view>
            </rewrite>
        </review>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

and

```
<?php
class Bbox_ExtendReview_Block_Product_View extends Mage_Review_Block_Product_View {
// some code
}
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The white space is not present in my config.xml I edited my question to remove that.